# How to create class object from class name and and use it for method overloading

Tags: java, reflection

To explain problem consider I have 6 classes

1. ClassOne
2. ClassTwo
3. ClassThree
4. ClassFour
5. ClassFive
6. ClassImpl

I have method `startOperation(List<String> classNameList)`, in this method I am iterating `classNameList` and for every class name I am using reflection to get object of the that class now I want to call method `doOperation()` which is an overloaded method.

```
private void doOperation(ClassOne objClassOne) {
    //Do somethig
}

private void doOperation(ClassTwo objClassTwo) {
    //Do somethig
}
.. And so on up to

private void doOperation(ClassFive objClassFive) {
    //Do somethig
}
```

my `startOperation` method looks like:

```
public void startOperation(List<string> classNameList) {
    for (String string : classNameList) {
        Class actualClass = Class.forName(className);
        Object classObj = actualClass.newInstance();
        doOperation(classObj); // here I am getting problem                             
    }
}
```

please tell how to call overloaded method from within the loop.

Note: `classNameList` dynamically contain names of different classes I don't want to hard code anything as some classes may get added to project or some may get removed I just want to add or delete respective `doOperation` method when this happen.

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: please show us the specific error which you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with reflection:

```
for (String string : classNameList) {
    Class actualClass = Class.forName(className);
    Object classObj = actualClass.newInstance();
    Method doOp = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("doOperation", actualClass);
    doOp.setAccessible(true);
    doOp.invoke(this, classObj);                            
}
```

Comment: it giving noSuchMethod exception

Comment: i guess private method cannot be retrieved like this because I have checked using this.getClass().getMethods() which returned all public methods

Answer (score 1):

One way is to hardcode the type check of `classObj`:

```
private void doOperation(final Object objClass)
{
    if(objClass instanceof ClassOne)
        doOperation((ClassOne)o);
    else if(objClass instanceof ClassTwo)
        doOperation((ClassTwo)o);
    else if(objClass instanceof ClassThree)
        doOperation((ClassThree)o);
    else if(objClass instanceof ClassFour)
        doOperation((ClassFour)o);
    else if(objClass instanceof ClassFive)
        doOperation((ClassFive)o);


}
```

Since you already hardcoded overloads of `doOperation` I guess this solution can fit your implementation.

Another way, is to use reflection to call the appropriate method:

```
public void startOperation(List<String> classNameList)
{
    for (String string : classNameList)
    {
        Class actualClass = Class.forName(className);
        Object classObj = actualClass.newInstance();
        Method doOperation = ClassImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("doOperation", actualClass);
        doOperation.setAccessible(true);//doOperation is private, we need to bypass that
        doOperation.invoke(this, classObj); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Method doOperation = ClassImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("doOperation", actualClass); at this point getting error NoSuchMethod found hence doOperation.setAccessible(true); is not getting executed

Comment: Are `doOperation` methods part of class `ClassImpl` ?